# Javascript Random problem?

Tags: javascript, random

```
var swf=["1.swf","2.swf","3.swf"];
var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*swf.length);

alert(swf[i]); // swf[1]  >> 2.swf
```

This case ,Random output `One` number.

How to Random output `two different numbers` ?

Comment: Please clarify what you're attempting to accomplish. If you need two random numbers, you can just execute the same code again. No?

Comment: I want 2 different number  swf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var swf = ['1.swf', '2.swf', '3.swf'],

// shuffle
swf = swf.sort(function () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1; });

// use swf[0]
// use swf[1]
```

---

Even though the above should work fine, for academical correctness and highest performance and compatibility, you may want to shuffle like this instead:

```
var n = swf.length;
for(var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var tmp = swf[i];
    swf[i] = swf[j];
    swf[j] = tmp;
}
```

Credits to tvanfosson and Fisher/Yates. :)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but should that 3 be `this.length` ?

Comment: @alex Nope. It's just randomly returning -1, 0 or 1 to randomly `sort` the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @deceze Ah, got it :) Thanks for the clarification. It's very clean too, so +1

Comment: I would typically expect the comparison function for sort to be deterministic.  Having it not be deterministic means you run the risk of having your sort not terminate -- since it may decide to keep swapping two entries, though in practice I doubt it would happen.  It would be better to use something like Fisher-Yates (http://bit.ly/eR3325) to shuffle which doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @tvanosson Interesting. I for one hadn't considered that.

Comment: @tvanfosson Good point, but the (Mozilla) documentation just states: `If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined` Which seems good enough for the intended purpose. :) Not sure if other JS engines handle it the same way though, so using the FY algorithm may be the correct thing to do.

Comment: @deceze -- Fisher-Yates is pretty simple and O(n) so it would be potentially faster than using sort to do this.

Comment: @LNXA - not sure what you mean about the problem, other than the obvious optimization of not swapping when `i === j`, I'm not seeing it.  Of course, it doesn't invalidate the algorithm to swap an element with itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use splice to remove the chosen element, then simply select another randomly.  The following leaves the original array intact, but if that's not necessary you can use the original and omit the copy.  Shown using a loop to demonstrate how to select an arbitrary number of times upto the size of the original array.

```
var swf=["1.swf","2.swf","3.swf"];
var elementsToChoose = 2;
var copy = swf.slice(0);
var chosen = [];

for (var j = 0; j < elementsToChoose && copy.length; ++j) {
   var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*copy.length);
   chosen.push( copy.splice(i,1) );
}

for (var j = 0, len = chosen.length; j < len; ++j) {
   alert(chosen[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do to require two numbers to be different (could be better answer out there)

```
var swf=["1.swf","2.swf","3.swf"];
var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*swf.length);
var j;
do {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random()*swf.length);
} while (j === i); 

alert(swf[i]);
alert(swf[j]);
```

**Edit**: should be `j===i`

Comment: The larger the array and the closer you get to choosing all of the elements, the longer this will take.  Using the Fisher-Yates shuffle and choosing the first N entries is probably the best, general answer.

Comment: Damn, just spot the error that made the code completely useless. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer this way as the bounds are known (you are not getting a random number and comparing it what you already have. It could loop 1 or 1000 times).

```
var swf = ['1.swf', '2.swf', '3.swf'],
    length = swf.length,
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    firstRandom = swf[i];

// I originally used `delete` operator here. It doesn't remove the member, just
// set its value to `undefined`. Using `splice` is the correct way to do it. 
swf.splice(i, 1);
length--;

var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * length),
    secondRandom = swf[j];


alert(firstRandom + ' - ' + secondRandom);
```

[Patrick DW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/patrick-dw) informed me of `delete` operator just leaving the value as `undefined`. I did some Googling and came up with this alternate solution.

Be sure to check [Tvanfosson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331155/javascript-random-problem/4331233#4331233) or [Deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331155/javascript-random-problem/4331210#4331210) for cleaner/alternate solutions.

Comment: `delete` doesn't compress the Array. It replaces the value with `undefined`. So you can end up with `"1.swf - undefined"`.

Comment: @alex - Comment out the `delete` line with an explanation, and replace it with `swf.splice(i,1);`.

Comment: @deceze Well I made an edit, cited the other two solutions and I linked and voted them up. Anything else I can do? :)

Comment: @alex - You have `list.splice(...` It should be `swf.splice(...`. You don't want the `=` assignment since `.splice()` modifies the original array. If you do `swf = swf.splice(...` then `swf` will equal the item that was removed.

Comment: `1.swf - 1.swf` or `1.swf - undefined`

Comment: @LNXA - Replace `swf = list.splice(i, 1);` with `swf.splice(i, 1);`

Comment: @patrick dw Thanks, I guess I shouldn't copy and paste if I'm going to miss basic stuff like that! Thanks again for pointing out the error of my ways.

Comment: has Problem, `1.swf - undefined`

Comment: @deceze You can go for that accepted answer now :D Edit: Oh wait, I'm back! :) Edit: There it goes again!

Comment: @alex - You must have accidentally deleted the `length--` adjustment in one of your edits. Needed since the `length` has changed.

Comment: Help! the second one = `undefined` when i `F5`